# unknown Servlet exception throw error of HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, servlets

I have tried adding all libraries that are needed for *Servlet* to run but still I am getting an exception that threw HTTP Status 500 error.

I also have tried all previously asked questions in stack overflow.

[image]

**LoginServlet.java**

```
package com.testlogin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {            
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.print("Hello");
        if (username.equals(password)) {
            pw.println("<h1>Hello </h1>" + username);
        }            
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {            
        doGet(req, resp);
    }        
}
```

**login.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
    <div style="color: red">
      User Name
      <input type="text" name="username">
      <br /> Password
      <input type="password" name="password">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
    </div>   
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your output? What exception are you getting? Could you post your code? Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: now u can see my output

Comment: But where is your code? There's no way we can help you with this if we don't understand what you were trying to do.

Comment: can u please see my code

Comment: where is your web.xml

Comment: I have used annotations.. I think no need of web.xml

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match the error in the screenshot.  Can you run it again and post an exact copy and paste of the code along with the resulting 500 error page info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, don't complicate your code. I think your code will work fine too and problem should be on your server. 
please make sure  if you are using servlet version >3.0 and tomcat 7 as it will not run in the previous versions of tomcat
try this..

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

response.setContentType("text/html");

String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
pw.print("Hello");
if (username.equals(password)) {
pw.println("<h1>Hello </h1>" + username);
}

}


}
```